# ld without -lstdc++ cannot find doctest

Tags: qt, cmake, qt5, c++17, clang++

I am working on a project under Windows and Ubuntu using CMake and CLang. On Ubuntu, I can build it OK with a shell script and could build it using Qt 5.5.1 (Creator 3.5.1). After upgrading to Qt 5.14.0 (Creator 4.11.1), there are over 1200 link errors where doctest cannot be found.

Captured compiler output:

```
[8/9 4.4/sec] Linking CXX executable test/test_runner
FAILED: : && /opt/clang+llvm-9.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04/bin/clang-9  -g -O0 -Wall -pthread --verbose   test/CMakeFiles/test_runner.dir/test_runner.cpp.o test/CMakeFiles/test_runner.dir/test.cpp.o  -o test/test_runner  PSCOM_LIB.a && :
clang version 9.0.0 (https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm c62b24f070c9a4bb1a76409e623042a740cac4cd)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
...
 "/usr/bin/ld" -z relro --hash-style=gnu --eh-frame-hdr -m elf_x86_64 -dynamic-linker /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 -o test/test_runner /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crti.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/crtbegin.o -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0 -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/lib/../lib64 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../.. -L/opt/clang+llvm-9.0.0-x86_64-linux-gnu-ubuntu-16.04/bin/../lib -L/lib -L/usr/lib test/CMakeFiles/test_runner.dir/test_runner.cpp.o test/CMakeFiles/test_runner.dir/test.cpp.o PSCOM_LIB.a -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed -lpthread -lc -lgcc --as-needed -lgcc_s --no-as-needed /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/crtend.o /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7.4.0/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crtn.o
test/CMakeFiles/test_runner.dir/test_runner.cpp.o: In function `doctest::detail::rawMemoryToString(void const*, unsigned int)':
/home/me/dev/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/doctest/doctest.h:2853: undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_ostringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_ostringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'
/home/me/dev/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/doctest/doctest.h:2854: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)'
/home/me/dev/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/doctest/doctest.h:2854: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Setfill<char>)'
/home/me/dev/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/doctest/doctest.h:2854: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(std::ios_base& (*)(std::ios_base&))'
/home/me/dev/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/doctest/doctest.h:2856: undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::_Setw)'
/home/me/dev/source/vcpkg_pml/vcpkg/installed/x64-linux/include/doctest/doctest.h:2856: undefined reference to `std::ostream::operator<<(unsigned int)'
```

and hundreds of similar errors in several files.

The shell script produces the following output.

```
 "/usr/bin/ld" ... -lstdc++ -lm -lgcc_s -lgcc -lpthread -lc -lgcc_s -lgcc ...
```

I have no idea why -lstdc++ is added or not but assume that it identifies the required doctest library. Is there an option that can be added to CMakeList.txt to correct this issue?

Comment: The title is misleading: In the error log you have `undefined references` to the functions which are part of **C++ standard library**. This problem is completely not a "cannot find doctest". As `stdc++` is an implementation of the C++ standard library, it seems logical that linking with that implementation fixes the problem.

Comment: Tsyvarev: feel free to suggest a better question. doctest does not link to the std library under Qt. It does from my shell script.